# How to open sharepoint summary links web part link in modal?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I know this will probably involve a content editor based on [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157650/on-click-of-summary-link-want-to-open-a-modal-popup). Also found [this one](https://samimkhan.wordpress.com/tag/sharepoint-summary-links-web-part-sharepoint-model-dialog/) about what should go in the CEWP, but I can't get it to work. Seeing NewItem2 in the function, am I supposed to replace this with something? Or is there a better way to write this?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: Working with 2013